# Meaning and differences between adding & multiplying two different functions in Physics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, dimensional-analysis, mathematics

We all know that acc. to Newtonian mechanics , $F = ma$ and acc. to Lagrangian-Hamiltonian mechanics , $H = T + V$. I want to ask what makes the Hamiltonian, $H = T + V$ and not $H = T × V$? Similarly, why $F = ma$ and not $F=m + a$ ? What is the difference between adding and multiplying two functions or quantities?
I need it because sometimes (mostly in Lagrangian mechanics) when I need to formulate the Lagrangian or Hamiltonian of a particular system I get stuck whether to add some functions or multiply them, **specially when a quantity of a formula is actually a function of two or more functions**. For eg. sometimes the potential energy of a mass in a system depends on *two* or more functions. In that case should I add or multiply those **functions** leaves me confused. Thus having the core concept and basics of formula mathematics is important.

Comment: From the definition of $L=T-V$ and the definition of $H$ it follows that $H=T+V$ for natural systems.  What else is there to say?  Just applying the definition does not yield $T\times V$.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero  I know the definition itself is the answer and in that way my question sounds stupid, but all I want to know is when to use multiplication between two functions and addition between two functions when formulating a quantity which is needed by formulas. I mean if we are completely new to a problem and proceed to formulate a unique solution / formula for that particular problem, we will need to have knowledge of when to multiply and when to add two or more functions during formulation. Sounds simpler now?

Comment: There is no such “rule”.   The total kinetic energy is the sum of the kinetic energies of the constituents.  The volume of a box is the product of the lengths of the box.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 4):

Probably the most important part of an answer to your question is that **Physics is not a bunch of mathematical objects to be combined in all possible ways**. Physics is a rational way to describe how our world works accurately enough to enable predictions.

Let's assume that we have introduced a few concepts, like mass, force, and acceleration or Hamiltonian, kinetic energy, and potential energy. A physicist does not start asking how many ways those quantities can be combined in an equation. Instead, a complex combination of experiments and theory suggests some important relations between the quantities, and such relations may suggest one or more possible equations.

In this game, there are a couple of general rules. In particular,

- all the terms appearing in an equation must be combined in a way consistent with their mathematical representation. This rule would exclude summing mass and acceleration once one has found, by doing experiments, that mass behaves as a scalar and acceleration like a vector. There is no mathematical structure where a vector can be added to a scalar.
- all the monomials appearing in an equation must have the same physical dimensions. This is a compact way to stress that quantitative relations between physical objects must be independent of the choice of the measurement units. For the same reason, all the arguments of non-monomial functions must be dimensionless. This rule would exclude an equation like $H=T \times V$.

According to these rules, formulas like $H=T+V$ and $H=T-V$ cannot be excluded. However, as I stated at the beginning of this answer, only the theory (or experiments) may show if both or only one of them is useful.

Comment: I like your answer but I wonder if answering such poorly researched questions is not encouraging such poorly researched questions…

Comment: @ZeroTheHero In general, I agree about not encouraging poorly researched questions. However, I think that a site like PSE is not intended only for prospective Ph.D. in Physics, and I got the impression that the OP probably needs some hints about the relations between math and physics. It is precisely the question that motivated me to answer: if somebody knows about Hamiltonians but asks this kind of question, he probably needs a hint about the proper perspective. Moreover, the answers may be helpful for others.

Comment: @GiorgioP I very much appreciate your response and your way to tackle the particular question Sir! Thank you once again.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero First of all I would like to apologise if my question seemed like a poorly framed one, as I could not exactly put the words together to describe what exactly I wanted to ask otherwise you wouldn't have had any trouble getting my question. Secondly, it seems funny to me why you are so bent on framing spam charges upon me! It really is funny. In PSE no one gets paid for asking question and neither I am seeking any popularity nor I am a bot. This site is for doubts and if my doubt is idiotic then many people wouldn't have answered it. Cheers and smile!

Comment: @PranjalSharma No need to apologize, although I would recommend you edit your question.  In particular if the point made at the top of this answer does not reflect what you meant to ask (I understood your question in the same way) then please correct the situation with an edit.

Comment: @GiorgioP Yes that’s a good point. +1.

Answer (score 1):

One important point about describing nature by mathematics is that we have to take into account that all our descriptions might only be approximate. Approximation is in large parts governed by Taylor's theorem, where we add up successive corrections to initial guesses, making the calculational results comply more and more with experiments. Suppose you want to describe a certain part of the world by an ordinary differential equation (first order, for the sake of simplicity), i.e. you have a vector of state variables $q$, which obey a differential equation of the form
$$\dot q = F(q)$$
The function $F$, which represents the physics in the part or domain of the world you are considering, may be arbitrarily complicated and nonlinear. You just don't know a-priori.

But as soon as you start trying to explain your experiments, you get dots (value pairs $(q,\dot q)$) in a plot of your experimental data, and if you have only a few dots that are not too far apart, they might always look like they represent a linear (or affine) relationship between $\dot q$ and $q$, so you make the ansatz
$$F(q)\approx A_0+A_1q$$
As you gain more and more experimental insight (more dots in the plot), especially if you let $q$ vary over a wider range, you might notice that the linear assumption starts to deteriorate, and you probably need a square function to explain the results better, i.e.
$$F(q)\approx A_0+A_1q+\langle q, A_3 q\rangle $$
(bear with me, if have hidden some vectorial indices, in order to not overload you)

And this possibly goes on an on as you continue experimenting. The theory that clarifies if and how the successively higher order polynomials improve the predictions is Taylor's theorem. Since Taylor series are additive, there is a overwhelming likelihood of getting natural laws that are also additive.

Note, that there are also other forms of series expansion (Fourier series, Multipole expansion, Legendre polynomials, Chebychev polynomials, and so on and so forth), all based on the requirement of obtaining a successively better approximation by getting additions at the top of the expression hierarchy.

However, this preference for addition is of course not a strict rule. You could always change variables by exponentiating them, and exponentiating a sum results in a product. In physics, there tend to be more exponentials and products besides sums in the field of thermodynamics. That is because statistical mechanics, on which thermodynamics is based nowadays, relies on entropy, whose definition includes a logarithm, which in turn preferredly leads to exponentials and products.

Comment: Great, your answer provides me some assurance and satisfaction. Experimental way is the best to breakdown and solve bigger problems composed of many functions.

Answer (score 0):

1. You may apply dimensional analysis. We do not add physical quantities together with different dimensions. For example, velocity and mass have different dimensions ($m/s$ and $kg$). It is not possible to add them together; however, it is possible to multiply them.
2. Another issue to be considered is linearity or inverse relationship. In the case of the Newton's law, if there is a body to be accelerated with acceleration $a$, the force should be proportional with both mass and acceleration. Hence, the law might be written as $F=ma$. However, for example, $F=m^2 a$ would not make sense, because in that case, the force would be proportional with mass squared not the mass itself.

Comment: Thank You so much! Yeah, the latter makes sense. But I feel that point no. 1 which you stated is more strategic in formulating solutions for problems often asked in entrance exams like GRE etc. Right?